# Ren'py launcher: "Cannot find Java SE Runtime environment"

Tags: java, renpy

Recently I botched an uninstall of an older version of Java and I've been having weird issues launching jEdit from the Ren'py engine since. First it keeps on trying to open Java from the wrong folder, and now it's telling me it can't find the Java SE Runtime.

I Googled for solutions, and I tried everything, but it's not working. I uninstalled and reinstalled Java, deleted all old Java registries and folders. I set the path in environment variables. Checked the Java paths in CMD, and everything looks fine. What am I doing wrong?

Worth noting that opening jEdit from jEdit.exe main install works, but launching it from Ren'py doesn't.

[image: Java_Home directory]

[image: Java version]

[image: Java Virtual Machine error]

And this is what Tom had to say about the Ren'py launcher

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The javaw.exe file located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 no longer works after the Java reinstall. I found a javaw.exe located in the newly-installed Java folder, copy-pasted it into SysWOW64, and it now works again.